# Where can I ask about static IP address vs. DHCP clarification?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have been doing some research on networking and I have been interested in static IP addresses. I have the following question:

> I was wondering if reserving a static IP address to certain devices in my home example (firestick, Raspberry Pi, and outdoor security cams) would benefit me in any way. I watched some videos and it seems a lot of gamers choose to configure their consoles to a static address for less lag. Would it do my devices any good to have static over dynamic addresses? Or is it mainly just used for servers?

I don't think this question is appropriate for Stack Overflow. On which other site within the SE network can I ask this question?

Comment: I'm not sure which search brought you here but the problem you describe will not be answered on this specific site. To get an answer from users that have the expertise about the topic of your question you'll have to find and then re-post on the [proper site](https://stackexchange.com/sites). Check [How do I ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) and [What is on topic](/help/on-topic) on the *target* site to make sure your post is in good shape. Your question is definitely off-topic on [Meta](/help/whats-meta) and is better deleted here.

Comment: sorry I thought this was a forum for what you just described

Comment: @MelissaChillington You are actually correct—but not in the way that you framed your question. To *locate* an appropriate site, phrase your question as *What is the best site for . . . ?* Then you can post a summary of the question you want to ask somewhere appropriate; it doesn't need to be (and probably shouldn't be) the complete text. Just enough so that people can figure out where to direct you to. By not framing this question in that way, it at least appears as if you had meant to get actual answers here rather than just redirection advice.

Comment: @MelissaChillington One site for the type of question you just outlined here is https://superuser.com/.

Comment: @MelissaChillington I've edited your question into something that is on-topic on this site. Please have a look and see if that still fits your needs.

Answer (score 3):

The root of your question seems to be about "personal and home computer networking", which is squarely [on-topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) at [Super User](https://superuser.com).

You might have to be careful with phrasing, though. "Would it do any good" is likely to be considered "too broad", and your question also skirts the borders of some things that are off-topic on SU:

> - video games or consoles
> - electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer

Depending on your computer(s)' operating systems, you *may* also get good results on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) (for Macs), [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com) (for Ubuntu), or [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com) (for UNIX/Linux other than Ubuntu).

I agree that SO is not a good place for this question. Most, if not all, other SE sites—including Network Engineering SE—don't seem like good fits either, whether because of their topics or the fact that they're more oriented towards professionals.